# Get screen info in windows 7

Tags: java, swing, awt

In my app I'm using swing and awt.  I am setting the size (and position) of the window  I'm creating based on toolkit.getScreenSize() and this works fine. But I would like to deal with the size of the windows 7 task bar at the bottom (or wherever) of the screen.  I can not seem to find out how to do this.  Anyone know how I can get the size if the task bar?

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to look at [java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment#getMaximumWindowBounds()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsEnvironment.html#getMaximumWindowBounds()), which returns the bounds of the screen area excluding the area covered by "objects in the native windowing system such as task bars and menu bars".

Answer (score 0):

Per Matthew's post I got going down the right path.  I was able to determine the windows bounds of the task bar with:

```
Insets scnMax = getToolkit().getScreenInsets(getGraphicsConfiguration());
taskBarSize = scnMax.bottom;
```

and then subtracting that value from a getScreenSize() height value to help me position the app window correctly.

Don't have a multi monitor system so I'm not sure how this works there but I will have to test that out.

Comment: Additionally what I look for is a value greater than zero in any of the scnMax.top, scnMax.bottom, scnMax.right, and scnMax.left and then adjust accordingly.